# R Spatial mapping: Creating intevals using the class interval function

Tags: r, intervals, r-maptools, colorbrewer

I am new to R and I am currently trying to create a choropleth map. My issue is that my breaks do not make sense. What I would like to do is to create breaks that equal:

under 59%
60-69%
70-79%
80-89%
over 90%

However what I get instead is:
under 60%
60-70%
70-80%
80-90%
over 90%

Does this mean that values=80 are featured in both categories?

My code for creating these breaks is:

```
colours<-brewer.pal(5,"Blues")

brks<-classIntervals(d.f$var,n=5,style= "fixed", fixedBreaks = 
c(50,60,70,80,90,100))

brks<-brks$brks

plot(d.f,col=colours[findInterval(d.f$var,brks,all.inside=TRUE)],axes=F)

box()

legend("topleft", legend=leglabs(brks), fill=colours, bty="n")
```

Answer (score 0):

`findInterval` uses [left-closed, right-open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29) intervals, as its help page explains, where you can override what happens on both ends. Try for instance:

```
> findInterval(10, c(0,10,20))
[1] 2
```

which indicates that `10` belongs to the second interval. For what you would like to do, the problem is in which interval would `69.5%` fall?